# Trying to target first 5 nth children and failing

Tags: css, css-selectors

with this

```
a:nth-child(n)::before
{
    content: "› ";
}

a:nth-child(n+1)::before
{
    content: "›› ";
}

a:nth-child(n+2)::before
{
    content: "››› ";
}

a:nth-child(n+3)::before
{
    content: "›››› ";
}

a:nth-child(n+4)::before
{
    content: "››››› ";
}
```

i am trying to get

› a1

›› a2

››› a3

›››› a4

››››› a5

but its not working... need help with this, have also tried just using 1,2,3,4,5 instead of n+1, etc... but that also doesn't work.

Comment: what browser are you testing with and what's the current result?

Comment: Do you need _each_ five links to be marked like that, or just the first one? If the former, you have to use `5n+1, 2, 3` expression, if the latter, digits will do [just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/2hTBH/), I suppose.

Comment: It seems nth-child is actually really versatile.  For the future reference of those who have the same issue, the documentation can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Comment: @Joseph Marikle: It is! Until you try to use it to filter by classes or attributes (which doesn't work)... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're already doing should work, even if it's probably not the best way to do it.

Here's a [edited version working](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/sY6Zc/):

```
a {
    display:block;
}
a:nth-child(1):before {
    content: "› ";
}
a:nth-child(2):before {
    content: "›› ";
}
a:nth-child(3):before {
    content: "››› ";
}
a:nth-child(4):before {
    content: "›››› ";
}
a:nth-child(5):before {
    content: "››››› ";
}​
```

With this HTML:

```
<a href="#">1</a><a href="#">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a><a href="#">4</a>
<a href="#">5</a>​
```

But won't work with this:

```
<a href="#">1</a><a href="#">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a><a href="#">4</a>
<div>5</div>
<a href="#">6</a>​
```

So, unless your layout is exactly the first one, you probably want to use [nth-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp).

You can also use [a single colon `:before`](http://www.impressivewebs.com/before-after-css3/)

Comment: i get 1,3,5,0,0 of ›'s (latest chrome btw :P)

Comment: your 2nd and 4th elements are <br>

Comment: omg i am so stupid. and the hint about that is in the actual answer above. and i missed it :( completely. now of course all is well - i deleted BR's

Comment: There is no need to change `::before` to `:before` since every browser that supports `:nth-child()` also supports double colons on pseudo-elements. If you're not supporting IE8 then it's recommended by W3C to adopt double colons going forward.

Comment: @BoltClock k  changed it back :P

Comment: Yup @BoltClock, the word "single colon" is actually a link explaining it (you _can_ != you _must_)

Answer (score 1):

I guess I haven't used that feature much yet, but it seems you have to specify `n+1` as your first one and go up from there:

```
a:nth-child(n+1)::before
{
  content: "› ";
}

a:nth-child(n+2)::before
{
  content: "›› ";
}

a:nth-child(n+3)::before
{
  content: "››› ";
}

a:nth-child(n+4)::before
{
  content: "›››› ";
}

a:nth-child(n+5)::before
{
  content: "››››› ";
}
```

Demo: 
http://jsbin.com/aboxop/1

Source: 
http://jsbin.com/aboxop/1/edit

EDIT:  Also, as @GionaF is getting at in his comment, this will only be supported in some browsers.  (Those that support CSS Selectors level 3)

Comment: It'll mark 6th and all the subsequent `a` elements with (n+5) style.

Comment: @raina77ow for me that is ok. there will always be exactly 5.

Comment: You're really better off specifying 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 to make it much clearer you're only targeting one element at a time. Self-documenting code and all.

Comment: @BoltClock how exactly? you mean not n+1 and n+2 but just 1 and 2??

Comment: @b0x0rz Of course. ) Did you check the JS fiddle in the comments?